# rxjs observable<entity> (array) count or lenght in typescript (angular 4)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to know how much elements are in an array like Observable.
I need just to retrive a number, not an Observable.
I lost a lot of time trying different operators, without success.

Here's the code:

```
entities: Observable<entity>;

let data = await this.myService.filter(2)
                    .subscribe(d => {this.entities= d; })
```

I'm using angular HttpClient, who sends an Observable directement from the response.  The service code is very simple:

```
filter(arg: int): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<entity>('/api/ent/find/' + arg.toString());}
```

The entities Observable is normally loaded, with multiples entities - I use it in a grid -. I just need something like

`howMany: number = entities.count() or entities.length()..`.

to get the quantity to use in the component (not to show).  And I got with different ways an Observable, when I need just a number.

Comment: Can you post your code? and some stuff you have tried? I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I updated the code, as demanded

Comment: can you post your service code? It is odd you are getting back an observable after subscribing

Comment: I updated the the post with the service code

Comment: I believe this is a typing issue. You are stating the property entities should be of type Observable<entity> when you are wanting it to be of type array (ie. entity[]). which leads to the 2nd type issue, you want entities to be an array of values, not a single value. so entities: entity[]. On a side note, angular recommends using PascalCase to signify an interface/class. https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#symbols-and-file-names

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have an `Observable<entity>` which returns an unknown number of results and you want to know that number. Here's one way to do it:

```
const entitie$: Observable<entity> = this.myService.filter(2).share(); // 1
let data: [entity] = []; // 2
let count: number = 0; // 3

entitie$.subscribe(ent => this.data.push(ent)); // 4
entitie$.reduce((state, curr) => state + 1, 0).subscribe(c => count = c); // 5
```

1. This makes the request to your service and shares the resulting observable between all subscribers. (If you don't use `share`, each subscriber will make one request each).
2. This is used to store the returned entities.
3. This will hold the number of entities returned by the observable.
4. This simply subscribes to the results returned by the request and pushes the received entities into the `data` array
5. This will start with the value `0` (as specified in the last parameter). For each new value (`curr`), it will add one to the stored value (`state`) and store that new value. When `entitie$` completes it will return the stored value, which is the number of returned entities.

Comment: Thanks you Jon, that hepls me

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the Observable and then you can get the length of the array

```
entities$: Observable<Entity[]>;
entities: Entity[];
this.myService.filter(2)
                .subscribe(value => this.entities= value);
```

Then you can use entities.length()

Comment: Yes but I get and Observable<number>, that I can't use to compute.  I updated the code.  Can you show me the full code please?

Comment: From the service I get entities$, because I use angualr HttpClient. By the way, it returns and Observable<entity>, not Observable<entities[]>.          And I can't found the way to transform entities$ to entities (Entity[])